# Sandbox dataloader

Tags: data-loader

When I login to data loader through sandbox it is throwing the below error:

> Invalid Session ID found in session Header

Can anyone suggest me in sorting out this?
This is working fine through my PROD login

Comment: It might be because you have logged in then the defined Session time of your salesforce instance. You should probably try logging out from your data loader and try login again. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to update your Server Host setting to point to the sandbox login domain, which is different to the one for PROD and DEV orgs.

[Steps for doing so:](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004931&type=1)

1. Start the Data Loader.
2. Click Cancel on the quick start screen.
3. Choose Settings.
4. Change the Server Host field to: `https://test.salesforce.com/`
5. Click "OK".

Comment: I am adding the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same salesforce user to login from different places (for ex., from Web) and logout, Salesforce actually invalidates all sessions. Check if you are using that user somewhere else and logging out there.